# Rich Snippet works with no html 5 pages?

Tags: html, seo, microdata, rich-snippets

I adding some Microdata in a page of a site. This site is standard html ,not html 5. I can add something like this without change heading of my pages?

```
 <div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Person">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Mark Pilgrim</h1>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microdata, which includes the `itemscope` and `itemtype` attributes is part of the HTML5 work so there's no standard doctype available for using microdata with earlier doctypes.

I think you have to change heading of your pages to HTML5. This is probably the best way forward.

But I also think that the consumers of the microdata are unlikely to care what doctype you are using.